# Amount exceeds maximum amount allowed Error in Razorpay in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, razorpay, flutter-razorpay

Please any one help me in this,
I make one application that accepts payment from users.
I use the Razorpay payment gateway.

here my payment code:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:razorpay_flutter/razorpay_flutter.dart';

    class PaymentPage extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      State<PaymentPage> createState() => _PaymentPageState();
    }
    
    class _PaymentPageState extends State<PaymentPage> {
      late var _razorpay;
      var amountController = TextEditingController();
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        _razorpay = Razorpay();
        _razorpay.on(Razorpay.EVENT_PAYMENT_SUCCESS, _handlePaymentSuccess);
        _razorpay.on(Razorpay.EVENT_PAYMENT_ERROR, _handlePaymentError);
        _razorpay.on(Razorpay.EVENT_EXTERNAL_WALLET, _handleExternalWallet);
        super.initState();
      }
    
      //payment succeds
      void _handlePaymentSuccess(PaymentSuccessResponse response) {
        // Do something when payment succeeds
        print("Payment Done");
      }
    
      //payment Fail
      void _handlePaymentError(PaymentFailureResponse response) {
        // Do something when payment fails
        print("Payment Fail");
      }
    
      void _handleExternalWallet(ExternalWalletResponse response) {
        // Do something when an external wallet is selected
      }
    
      void lunchRazorPay() {
        int amountToPay = int.parse(amountController.text) * 100;
    
        ///Make payment
        var options = {
          'key': "rzp_test_dLlOPoSwRLpQJE",
          'amount': "$amountToPay",
          'name': 'JMC',
          'description': 'Donate',
          'timeout': 300, // in seconds
          'prefill': {'contact': '', 'email': ''}
        };
    
        try {
          _razorpay.open(options);
        } catch (e) {
          print(e);
        }
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
        return Scaffold(
          //Heading Part
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Color(0xFF22E183),
    
            //for back arrow option
            leading: IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context, false);
              },
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.arrow_back,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
    
            title: const Center(
              child: Text(
                'Donating           ',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontFamily: 'Gotham'),
              ),
            ),
            elevation: 0,
          ),
    
          //body part
          body: Container(
            height: size.height,
            width: size.width,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 30),
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: amountController,
                    decoration:
                        const InputDecoration(hintText: "Enter your Amount"),
                  ),
                ),
                CupertinoButton(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  child: Text("Pay Amount"),
                  onPressed: lunchRazorPay,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    
      @override
      void dispose() {
        _razorpay.clear();
        super.dispose();
      }
    }
```

and I use Test card money from [https://razorpay.com/docs/payments/payments/test-card-upi-details/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWG9u.jpg)

my payment page load and work goodly but all the time my payment goes fails.
I have not screened for accepte and rejecte payments.

[image]
Please help me how to solve this problem!

Comment: Having the same issue, is there any fix?

Comment: @NasyxNadeem yes!! i made one mistake when I made an account on rozerpay. when you create your Rozerpay account then don't fill in any Organization detail, make account using only pancard and problem solved!!

Comment: Facing same issue. Support is not answering anything.